# Printing a dot in Terminal while looking for a word

Tags: bash

Let's say we have a bash that output the output of it is commands ( which are showing up in terminal) to a log file as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 
exec 1> logfile.log # logfile.log contains all what will be printed in terminal and it will keep updating its content till the script finish it is job
command#1
command#2
command#3
.
.
.
.
.
echo -n "Process is DONE ..."
exec 1>&3
exec 3>&-
```

If this script needs minutes to finish it is work by running the commands included within it one by one.

How can this script print a dot every one second till it find the sentence "Process is DONE within the file "logfile.log" ? Or create any motion on the screen ( i.e. progress bar or snipper) just to show that the process is still alive?

Comment: @ don_crissti I revised the question to make it more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design you use seems to me unduly devious. You might consider the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=logfile.log

#echo $i #what's this for?
exec 3>&1 
exec 1> "$LOG" # logfile.log contains all what will be printed in terminal and it will keep updating its content till the script finish it is job
#command1 &
sleep 5 &
sleep 10 &
sleep 15 &
for i in {1..7}; do
    echo x
    sleep 1
done &
#command2 &
#command3 &
#and so on...

exec 1>&3
exec 3>&- 
echo Progress:
while [ $(jobs -pr | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; do 
    #jobs
    echo -n "."
    sleep 1
done

echo -e "\nProcess is DONE ..." | tee -a "$LOG"
```

There are a few illustrative lines added:

- lines 9-15 are example commands
- line 24 can be unhashed to show the logic

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to look for that certain string, or is it enough to just stop watching when the process ends? A simple-ish way might be to pipe the output through `pv` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)) to get a progress bar, and may be check the `tail` of the output file at the end to see what happened last.

Made up example:

```
./process.sh  | pv > output.file ; tail -1 output.file 
  34 B 0:00:02 [16.8 B/s] [   <=>                                ]
Process done.
```

Comment: Actually looking for the string is an attempt to solve the problem. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Can I use  pv inside the script ?

Comment: @goro, mm, if it were me, I'd prefer tools that print to stdout, as it's easier to post-process the output in a pipeline, or to choose the file to redirect the output to (esp. hardcoding an output file name is annoying if one needs to make two separate runs). For `pv`, you do need some way to push the output from all your commands to a file. Making a separate script for the inner part, or running it in a subshell, i.e. `(cmd1 ; cmd2) | pv > output` might be simplest. (I can't remember if `exec` can redirect to a pipeline)